# Highchart pie intersection area

Tags: highcharts, intersection, pie-chart

I use highchart to draw two charts(both pie style).
One represents those people who use app1 and the other represents those people who use app2.
So what should I do , if I want the two pies join together to get a common area to represent hose people who use both app1 and app2?
Great thanx! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Highcharts you can manage pie charts using `center: [x, y]` for example: http://jsfiddle.net/FP8By/3/

Comment: Yes , but the percentage of the common area should represent those people who use both app1 and app2 .So how shold I define the common area?I can not just let two pies jion together...it's meaningless...